# Adding prev next navigation to list items fade in/out loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have the following code that loops through list items making them fade in/out, it works but I'd need some help adding a prev next navigation as well without duplicating any code.

HTML:

```
<ul id="site_slideshow_inner_text">
    <li>List item 1</li>
    <li>List item 2</li>
    <li>List item 3</li>
    <li>List item 4</li>
</ul>
```

JQUERY

```
$(function () {
    var list_slideshow = $("#site_slideshow_inner_text"),
        listItems = list_slideshow.children('li'),
        listLen = listItems.length,
        i = 0,
        changeList = function () {
            listItems.eq(i).fadeOut(300, function () {
                i += 1;
                if (i === listLen) {
                    i = 0;
                }
                listItems.eq(i).fadeIn(300);
            });
        };
    listItems.not(':first').hide();
    setInterval(changeList, 1000);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Q6kp3/

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What you want to happen on click of prev and next, because you are infinitely looping on load, does that needs to stop?

Comment: Thanks, that's part of the problem actually. I want them to loop automatically, but also add next/prev to manually control it. The loop should stop when it's controlled by buttons

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this way making it more generic:

```
 var 
        $listItems = $("#site_slideshow_inner_text").children('li'),
        fadeDuration = 300,
        interval;
    $listItems.not(':first').hide();

    function showSlide(elm) {
        //fadeout the visible one and fade in the element passed to the function
        $listItems.filter(':visible').fadeOut(fadeDuration, function () {
            elm.fadeIn(fadeDuration);
        });
    }

    function autoSlide() {
    //auto slide is set up to go forward
        interval = setInterval(function () {
            showSlide( getNextElement('next'));
        }, 1000);
    }

    $('#prev, #next').on('click', function () {
        stopAutoSlide(); //stop auto slide 
        showSlide(getNextElement(this.id)); //Get next element by passing in prev/next as argument which are the id of the element itself.
    });


    //Here is the major section that does all the magic of selection the element
    function getNextElement(direction) {
    //Here direction will be prev or next they are methods on jquery to select the element, so it will select correspoding element by executing that specific function i.e next() or prev(). 
     // Also set up a fallback if there is no element in  next or prev you need to go to last or first and execute it.
        var $next = $listItems.filter(':visible')[direction](), 
            fallBack = (direction === 'prev' ? 'last' : 'first');
        return !$next.length ? $listItems[fallBack]() : $next;

    }

    function stopAutoSlide() {
        $listItems.stop(true, true, true); //just clean up the animation queues
        clearInterval(interval); //clear the interval
    }

    autoSlide(); //Kick off auto slide
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/K3zdB/)**

Comment: @djwd This is the answer to study... A bit complicated but lots of wow tricks. +1

Comment: Updated the answer with comments.. :) Hope it makes sense

Comment: Wow thanks I just saw that. I don't think there were any need to downvote though, I just accepted the first working answer to my question. Looking at yours right now trying to understand the practical advantages, thanks for all the comments as well.

Comment: Ok sorry I though you were upset ;) Don't know who did and why then, doesn't matter. Thanks for your help

Comment: @djwd lol.. i gave you a +1 to negate the d/v you got... I have answered enough questions to get upset about that.. :)

Comment: Very well explained, detailed, and commented.  Also it will not display multiple list items if you click very fast, as mine did.  Well done.

Comment: @Bryan Thanks, yes that magic is done by stopAutoSlide() which also cleans up the animation queues.. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can stop the automatic loop my creating a variable such as `var x = setInterval(changelist,1000);` Then later call `clearInterval(x);`

As for the previous and next controls, you can set on 'next' click to clearInterval and then call the changeList() function.  For the prev, you will have to create another function, where you subtract 1 from i and check if i === -1, set it to the last item.

See here:
http://jsfiddle.net/upPp4/1

Comment: Works great! Thank you very much for the detailed explaination, I'm studying your example now, thanks again Bryan.

Comment: This is an excellent answer and matches the OPs initial approach. +1 Good job. Hard to compete against PSL, though... I'm sure the OP learned lots from both of you.

Comment: @gibberish i second that, +1 from my side too. @ Bryan I am sure you will be able to write much better than i did as you go... We all learn from SO and give back to SO.. :)

Answer (score 2):

To stop the loop, you must assign the setInterval to a variable:

```
var myInt = setInterval(changeList, 1000);
```

and then call that handle with clearInterval:

```
clearInterval(myInt);
```

Then, just call your function again:

```
changeList();
```

So your button code would look something like (untested):

```
<input id="next" type="button" value=">">
<input id="prev" type="button" value="<">


$('#next').click(function() {
    clearInterval(myInt);
    changeList;
});
```

Comment: +1 for you too... :) All are great answers with different approaches.. :)